# keras usage of the Activation layer instead of activation parameter

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

There is an Activation layer in Keras.

Seems this code:

```
  model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
```

and this one:

```
  model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
```

produces the same result.

What is the purpose of this additional **Activation** layer?

[Upgr: 2017-04-10] Is there a difference in performance with above two scenarios?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you may see, both approaches are equivalent. I will show you a few scenarios in which having this layer might help:

1. **Same layer - different activations**- one may easily imagine a net where you want to have different activations applied to the same output. Without `Activation` it's impossible.
2. **Need for output before activation** - e.g. in *siamese networks* you are training your network using `softmax` as final activation - but in the end - you want to have so called `logits` - inverse `softmax` function. Without additional `Activation` layer that could be difficult.
3. **Saliency maps:** in saliency maps - similiar to what you have in a previous point - you also need output before activation in order to compute a gradient w.r.t. to it - without `Activation` it wouldn't be possible.

As you may see - lack of `Activation` would make output of a layer before activation and final activation strongly coupled. That's why `Activation` might be pretty useful - as it breaks this ties.